# Question on dsPIC33F PWM Period and Duty Cycle Calculation

Tags: pic, pwm

On the Microchip dsPIC33F family, the PWM period **PTPER** is calculated as:

> PTPER = (FCY/FPWM)*(PTMR Prescaler Value) - 1

where PTMR is the input clock to the PWM and **FCY = Fosc/2**, FCY being the instruction cycle frequency and Fosc the main clock frequency. It is specified that the input clock to **PTMR** is *Fosc/4* **(ref. doc: DS70165D-page 178)**.
Does this mean that the period is calculated in instruction cycle clock ticks, or twice the instruction cycle clock ticks? Does this information relate to why multiply PTPER by 2 in the following line of code (taken from Microchip Application Note AN957):

```
PDC1 = (int)(((long)(PTPER*2)*(long)DutyCycle) >> 15); // why multiply PTPER by 2?
PDC2 = PDC1;                      // PDCx is the duty cycle register for PWMx channel
PDC3 = PDC2;                      // x = 1,2,3
```

In my understanding, the factor of **2** shouldn't be there. A more complete version of this code was posted yesterday at this forum:
[Help understanding the code](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163650/help-understanding-the-code)

Comment: The clock prescaler beings used is `1:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. In this MCU family, the PWM timer clock is slower than the duty cycle clock. If a 1:1 prescaler is selected for PWM clock, for each timer clock tick there are two duty cycle clock ticks. Therefore, the factor of 2 is multiplied in duty cycle calculation.

*Duty cycle clock period = TCY/2*;
*PWM Timer PTMR Clock period = TCY (1:1 prescaler used)*

Source: **dsPIC33F/PIC24H Family Reference Manual - DS70187E (pp. 14-34 & 14-35)**

Comment: Self explanatory.